# Error when covnerting japanese text in bytes to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, byte

I am trying to extract an srt from zip file:

When I read the srt file, I get bytes object of a japanese text file as follows:

```
bov = b'1\r\n00:00:06,000 --> 00:00:12,074\r\n\x8dL\x8d\x90\x8fo\x8de\x82\xf0\x82\xa8\x8dl\x82\xa6\x82\xcc\x95\xfb\x82\xd6\r\n\x82\xa8\x96\xe2\x82\xa2\x8d\x87\x82\xed\x82\xb9\x82\xcd www.OpenSubtitles.org \x82\xdc\x82\xc5\r\n\r\n2\r\n'

sv = bov.decode()
```

Decoding gives errors as follows:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 34: invalid start byte
```

Expected text is as follows:

`1 00:00:42,521--> 00:00:46,062 嘘の代償はいくらですか？`

`l.decode(errors="ignore")` gives me

`'1\r\n00:00:06,000 --> 00:00:12,074\r\nLoel̕\r\n₢킹 www.OpenSubtitles.org ܂\r\n\r\n2\r\n'`

Comment: I think there is a problem with the expected output for the provided input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
bov = b'1\r\n00:00:06,000 --> 00:00:12,074\r\n\x8dL\x8d\x90\x8fo\x8de\x82\xf0\x82\xa8\x8dl\x82\xa6\x82\xcc\x95\xfb\x82\xd6\r\n\x82\xa8\x96\xe2\x82\xa2\x8d\x87\x82\xed\x82\xb9\x82\xcd www.OpenSubtitles.org \x82\xdc\x82\xc5\r\n\r\n2\r\n'
sv = bov.decode('shift_jis_2004')

print(sv)
```

Which gives:

```
1 00:00:06,000 --> 00:00:12,074 広告出稿をお考えの方へ お問い合わせは www.OpenSubtitles.org まで

2
```

Only thing that was needed is to specify the right codex, taken from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html